# Error 2029 by "VBA Excel 365 Home Insider/Beta" => Function "Application.Evaluate" with a lambda expression with double recursion (Fibonacci)

Tags: excel, vba, lambda, runtime-error, evaluate

The following UDF Function (Lambda Expression) with the name "UDF_FIBO" ist stored in the Name Manager (expression stored as Referer as needed without Parameter)

Name:

`UDF_FIBO`

Referer:

`=LAMBDA(myVal; IF(myVal>1; IF(myVal>2; UDF_FIBO(myVal-1)+UDF_FIBO(myVal-2);1);1))`

**Testing it in a  Worksheet in a cell, it's working fine.**

**In VBA (immediate Window) I'm getting an "Error 2029"**

Error 2029

The Error Handler shows no Errors
Err.Number 0
Err. Source
Err. Description
Err.LastDllError 0

```vb
Sub double_recursion()

    my = "=LAMBDA(myVal, IF(myVal>1, IF(myVal>2, UDF_FIBO(myVal-1)+UDF_FIBO(myVal-2),1),1))(10)"

    Debug.Print Application.Evaluate(my)
    
End Sub
```

**If I'm changing the string to a simple recursion there is a (wrong) result available (wrong math formel, so it's not a solution)**

```vb
Sub simple_recursion()

    my = "=LAMBDA(myVal,IF(myVal>1,IF(myVal>2,UDF_FIBO(myVal-1),1),1))(10)"

    Debug.Print Application.Evaluate(my)
    
End Sub

Testing it with 

Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=UDF_FIBO(10)") is also working fine => Result is correct => 55
```

Chris

Connotation about my system:

I have to use commas for separating variables in VBA whereas I have to use semicolons within Excel spreadsheet formulas, maybe you have to change this sign due to your environment.

Comment: Worth adding Excel version info as this won't be available to everyone. This was insiders only but may now have changed. Also, add the error code description to go with the number.

Comment: [Unsure relevant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) but _when you use the Evaluate command, Excel immediately returns the result of the LAMBDA function_

Comment: I added the information you suggested, thxs!

Comment: The debugging is really in the beta phase, you're right...

I'm developing an excel document where you can enter a Lambda Expression and a Name. You can click on a button to save it to the Namemanager and the Result is being transferred to the worksheet to make the process much more easier. This is working already fine, the only thing is the internal evaluation of some Lamda statements, the UDF evaluation by Name: Application.Evaluate("=UDF_FIBO(10)") works fine, even within VBA using Application.evaluate() Probably this is a different evaluation than the one within the spreadsheet...